# Is it possible to send second request over persistent connection, before response is returned. Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

I know it sound strange but the situation is strange. I have been trying to send second request to the server(over the same connection) before the first response. What I get is response to the first request and the second one is ignored by the server. The server keeps the connection alive:

```
server.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.setTimeout(50 * 1000);
  socket.on("timeout", () => {
    console.log("socket timeout");
    socket.end();
  });

  socket.on("close", hadError => {
    console.log(
      hadError
        ? "Socket closed due to ERROR during transmission"
        : "Socket closed"
    );
  });
});
```

This is the route that handles the request:

```
app.post("/enddev", (req, res) => {
  console.log("REQUEST TO ", req.route.path);
  console.log("Req Header ", req.headers);

  res.write("request\r\n");
  setInterval(() => {
    res.write("ack\r\n");
  }, 2000);
});
```

I think that the **HTTP protocol** does not allow this, but may be there is some workaround.

**Websockets** are not solutions because the client is (not a browser) an embedded device.

And here is an image of the test (I use a TCP client terminal program ti simulate the request message from the client):

[image]

The right terminal (black one) is the node server. The white one is the terminal. On the terminal in pink is is what the client sent. In black is the response from the server. You can see that the server sends `"request"` message right after the header. But upon second request no response appears.

Comment: Can you post the route controller code that sends the response? "The second request is ignored by the server" sounds like you close the connection after the response.

Comment: @msanford

Edited the post. Hope this shed some more light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're ever calling `res.end()`. Without that, node.js thinks your response is not over yet.

Comment: Yes you are right. However I don't think that is necessary. The following is from HTTP spec: HTTP requests and responses can be pipelined on a connection. Pipelining allows a client to make multiple requests without waiting for each response, allowing a single TCP connection to be used much more efficiently, with much lower elapsed time.

Comment: @Hairi `res.end()` does not end the TCP connection. It signals that the response is done. Pipelining is not really support anywhere. No browser supports it. However, your client really does support it, you still need to tell node that the HTTP response is complete.

Comment: However, connection re-use in HTTP/1.1 is still a thing, but telling node that your response is ready to go is regardless a must.